# what are the unforseen consequences to using visudo to enable wheel group to run all sudo commands?

Tags: centos, security, sudo, group, su

On `CentOS release 5.11 (Final)` I created a user and added them to the wheel group with `usermod` but when I look in the sudoers file at `/etc/sudoers` the relevant line is commented out.  Looking at groups:

```
[root@arrakis ~]# 
[root@arrakis ~]# grep wheel /etc/group
wheel:x:10:root,hawat
[root@arrakis ~]# 
[root@arrakis ~]# su hawat
[hawat@arrakis root]$ 
[hawat@arrakis root]$ cd
[hawat@arrakis ~]$ 
[hawat@arrakis ~]$ whoami
hawat
[hawat@arrakis ~]$ 
[hawat@arrakis ~]$ sudo echo "hello sudo"
[sudo] password for hawat: 
hawat is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
[hawat@arrakis ~]$
```

and

```
[root@arrakis ~]# 
[root@arrakis ~]# groups wheel ; getent passwd hawat
id: wheel: No such user
hawat:x:505:505::/home/hawat:/bin/bash
[root@arrakis ~]#
```

Taking a closer look at `sudoers`:

```
[root@arrakis ~]# 
[root@arrakis ~]# grep wheel /etc/sudoers
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL)   ALL
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
[root@arrakis ~]#
```

I hesitate to uncomment those lines so that the wheel group can run all commands with `sudo`.  This is an `Elastix 2.5` system on `CentOS`; perhaps there's a reason not to have `wheel` in the sudo list?

Should I just go ahead an manually edit `sudoers` with `visudo`?

Answer (score -1):

Certainly, uncommenting the line `%wheel    ALL=(ALL)   ALL` with visudo allows, apparently, `sudo` to work correctly.  Emphasis on **apparently**.  Again, this is Elastix 2.5 on CentOS, neither of which are familiar.  If this is "ok" then that would be the answer to the question.  The `sudoers` file:

```
[root@arrakis ~]# 
[root@arrakis ~]# grep wheel /etc/sudoers
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
 %wheel ALL=(ALL)   ALL
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
[root@arrakis ~]#
```

Now that the wheel group is enabled, apparent success:

```
[root@arrakis ~]# 
[root@arrakis ~]# su hawat
[hawat@arrakis root]$ 
[hawat@arrakis root]$ cd
[hawat@arrakis ~]$ 
[hawat@arrakis ~]$ sudo echo "foo"
[sudo] password for hawat: 
foo
[hawat@arrakis ~]$
```

Are there alternate solutions?  Does this negatively impact security, the OS or Elastix in some way?  I don't know the answer to those questions.